# implement devise-like "current_user" method in RubyMotion App

Tags: ios, devise, rubymotion

I am an Objective C noob and learning to build apps with RubyMotion.

I want to be able to call **current_user** and get the currently logged in user to my app.

Right now I am sending the current_user record from the server and calling **User.new(:user)** when a user logs in, but I can't call this user globally the way I'd like to, and send it into a Formotion edit form, etc

Right now I am initializing models using the KVO as described in the [ruby tutorial](http://rubymotion-tutorial.com/7-models/) Should I implement **MotionModel**? How would I use that tool to get that ready-at-hand current_user method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a class method in the user model.

```
User.current_user
```

Your user class:

```
class User

  def self.current_user
    @current_user ||= begin
      # get your user here, using BubbleWrap's App::Persistence or another persistence mechanism.
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to send the current_user's id back with the login response, then store it in

```
App::Persistence['currentUserId']
```

Then when you call the user detail controller create a custom "initWithId" method that takes the id as an argument.

```
UserDetailController.alloc.initWithId(App::Persistence['currentUserId'])
```